# How to sort word count program by value or count?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

How do I sort my wordcount output by count/value rather than by the key.

In the normal case, the output is

```
hi 2
hw 3 
wr 1 
r 3
```

but the desired output is

```
wr 1
hi 2
hw 3
r 3
```

My code is:

```
public class sortingprog {
     public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, IntWritable, Text> {
         private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
         private Text word = new Text();

         public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<IntWritable, Text> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
           String line = value.toString();
           StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
           while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
             word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
             output.collect(one,word);
           }
         }
       }


     public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<IntWritable,Text, IntWritable, Text> {
     public void reduce(Iterator<IntWritable> key, Text value, OutputCollector<IntWritable, Text> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
            int sum=0;
           while (key.hasNext()) {
             sum+=key.next().get();
           }
           output.collect(new IntWritable(sum),value);

     }

    @Override
    public void reduce(IntWritable arg0, Iterator<Text> arg1,
            OutputCollector<IntWritable, Text> arg2, Reporter arg3)
            throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
     }

     public static class GroupComparator extends WritableComparator {
            protected GroupComparator() {
                super(IntWritable.class, true);
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
            @Override
            public int compare(WritableComparable w1, WritableComparable w2) {
                IntWritable v1 = (IntWritable) w1;
                IntWritable v2 = (IntWritable) w2;          
                return -1 * v1.compareTo(v2);
            }
        }

       public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
         JobConf conf = new JobConf(sortingprog.class);
         conf.setJobName("wordcount");


         conf.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
         conf.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);


         conf.setMapperClass(Map.class);
         conf.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

         conf.setOutputValueGroupingComparator(GroupComparator.class);

         conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
         conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

         FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
         FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));

         JobClient.runJob(conf);
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you look for is called "Secondary Sort". Here you can find two tutorials of how to achieve a value short in your MapReduce:

http://vangjee.wordpress.com/2012/03/20/secondary-sorting-aka-sorting-values-in-hadoops-mapreduce-programming-paradigm/

http://codingjunkie.net/secondary-sort/

Answer (score 0):

you need to do the following.

1. Create a custom writable comparable which uses both the fields.
2. In the compareTo method provide the implementation logic of comparing the custom writable. This is called by the Reducer later to sort the keys. That is key in the whole implementation. Here in the compareTo just use the second field to compare the values.

`public CustomPair implements WritableComparable{
    public CustomPair(String fld1,int fld2){
       this.fld1=fld1; //wr
       this.fld2=fld2;//1
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o2) {
        CustomPair other = (CustomPair ) o2;
        int compareValue = other.fld2().compareTo(this.fld2());
        return compareValue;
   }
   public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
     dataOutput.writeUTF(fld1);
     dataOutput.writeInt(fld2);
   }
// You have to implement the rest of the methods.

}`
Let me know if you need additional help.